# T-SQL variable more than 8000 characters

Tags: sql-server, variables, varchar

I have a problem... I need put more than 8000 characters into a variable. I read that the limit is 2Gb but why is limited to print at 8000 chars?

I have read that I can create 2 variable but first is no correct, if I print @var1+@var2 I see only 8000 chars and after I populate the var from a STUFF and explode all row to a line, I can separate it....

How I can resolve?

Comment: For print varchar can use this is https://ask.sqlservercentral.com/questions/3102/any-way-around-the-print-limit-of-nvarcharmax-in-s.html

Comment: `PRINT` is limited to 8,000 bytes of data. This is [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/print-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#remarks). The problem has *nothing* to do with variables.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server can **definitely** store more than 8'000 characters into a `varchar(max)` column (or variable) - provided you make sure at least one of the variables / values involved really **IS** of type `varchar(max)`.

Let's see an example

```
DECLARE @LongVar VARCHAR(MAX);

SET @LongVar = REPLICATE('abcde', 40000);

SELECT DATALENGTH(@LongVar)
```

Even though you're specifying 40'000 repetitions of those 5 characters, this will result in 8'000 characters stored in `@LongVar` - because **none** of the expressions involved really **are** of type `varchar(max)`.

If you change this to:

```
DECLARE @LongVar VARCHAR(MAX);

SET @LongVar = REPLICATE(CAST('abcde' AS VARCHAR(MAX)), 40000);

SELECT DATALENGTH(@LongVar)
```

Now **THIS** results in 200'000 characters being stored in `@LongVar` - **because** the five characters being repeated are casted to be of type `varchar(max)`  ..